# The following _Exception was thrown building BlocBuilder<RecipeBloc, RecipeState>(dirty, dependencies:

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, bloc

I was trying to fetch data using API and Bloc builder in a flutter. But I am getting an error while running the bloc. Here is my code. I have also added an error screenshot below the code. Thanks.

**Main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:footballplayers/services/api_services.dart';

import 'homeScreen.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MultiRepositoryProvider(
        providers: [
          RepositoryProvider(
            create: (context) => ApiServices(),
          ),
        ],
        child: HomeScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**HomeScreen.dart**

```
// ignore_for_file: public_member_api_docs, sort_constructors_first
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/foundation/key.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:footballplayers/bloc/recipe_bloc.dart';

import 'package:footballplayers/models/recipe_model.dart';
import 'package:footballplayers/services/api_services.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) =>
          RecipeBloc(RepositoryProvider.of<ApiServices>(context))
            ..add(GetRecipeEvent()),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          title: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Icon(
                Icons.restaurant_menu,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              Text(
                'FoodRecipe',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: BlocBuilder<RecipeBloc, RecipeState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            if (state is RecipeLoading) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
            if (state is RecipeLoaded) {
              return Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: state.recipeData.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return recipeCard(
                        imgUrl: state.recipeData[index].imgUrl,
                        recipeName: state.recipeData[index].name,
                        rating: state.recipeData[index].rating,
                        totalTime: state.recipeData[index].totalTime,
                      );
                    }),
              );
            } else {
              throw Exception('Something went wrong');
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class recipeCard extends StatelessWidget {
  String imgUrl;
  String recipeName;
  double rating;
  String totalTime;
  recipeCard({
    Key? key,
    required this.imgUrl,
    required this.recipeName,
    required this.rating,
    required this.totalTime,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Column(children: [
        ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            child: Image.network(
              imgUrl,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            )),
        Text(
          recipeName,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 18,
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 224, 63),
                ),
                child: Text(
                  rating.toString(),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 15,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 70, 18, 224),
                ),
                child: Text(
                  totalTime,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 15,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

**ApiServices.dart**

```
    import 'dart:convert';
    
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:footballplayers/models/recipe_model.dart';
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
    
    class ApiServices {
      List<RecipeModel> recipeList = [];
    
      Future<List<RecipeModel>> getRecipe() async {
        final uri = Uri.https(
            'yummly2.p.rapidapi.com', '/feeds/list', {'limit': '24', 'start': '0'});
    
        final response = await http.get(
          uri,
          headers: {
            'X-RapidAPI-Key': '80cb4acef6mshf3b62df4bcdc92ap1b8e20jsna293a3b01f0f',
            'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'yummly2.p.rapidapi.com',
          },
        );
        final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
        final values = data['feed'];
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
          if (values[i]['content']['details']['name'] != null) {
            RecipeModel recipeModel = RecipeModel(
              name: values[i]['content']['details']['name'] as String,
              imgUrl: values[i]['content']['details']['images'][0]['hostedLargeUrl']
                  as String,
              totalTime: values[i]['content']['details']['totalTime'] as String,
              rating: values[i]['content']['details']['rating'] as double,
            );
            recipeList.add(recipeModel);
          }
        }
        return recipeList;
      }
    }

**RecipeModel.dart**

// ignore_for_file: public_member_api_docs, sort_constructors_first
class RecipeModel {
  String name;
  String imgUrl;
  String totalTime;
  double rating;
  RecipeModel({
    required this.name,
    required this.imgUrl,
    required this.totalTime,
    required this.rating,
  });

  factory RecipeModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return RecipeModel(
      name: json['name'],
      imgUrl: json['images'][0]['hostedLargeUrl'],
      totalTime: json['totalTime'],
      rating: json['rating'],
    );
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'RecipeModel(name: $name, imgUrl: $imgUrl, totalTime: $totalTime, rating: $rating)';
  }
}
```

**RecipeBloc.dart**

```
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:footballplayers/models/recipe_model.dart';
import 'package:footballplayers/services/api_services.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

part 'recipe_event.dart';
part 'recipe_state.dart';

class RecipeBloc extends Bloc<RecipeEvent, RecipeState> {
  final ApiServices apiServices;
  List<RecipeModel> recipeD = [];
  RecipeBloc(this.apiServices) : super(RecipeInitial()) {
    on<GetRecipeEvent>((event, emit) async {
      emit(RecipeLoading());
      final activity = await apiServices.getRecipe();
      recipeD = apiServices.recipeList;

      emit(RecipeLoaded(recipeData: recipeD));
    });
  }
}
```

**RecipeBlocEvent.dart**

```
part of 'recipe_bloc.dart';

@immutable
abstract class RecipeEvent {}

class GetRecipeEvent extends RecipeEvent {}
```

**RecipeBlocState.dart**

```
// ignore_for_file: public_member_api_docs, sort_constructors_first
part of 'recipe_bloc.dart';

abstract class RecipeState {}

class RecipeInitial extends RecipeState {}

class RecipeLoading extends RecipeState {}

class RecipeLoaded extends RecipeState {
  List<RecipeModel> recipeData;
  RecipeLoaded({
    required this.recipeData,
  });

  @override
  String toString() => 'RecipeLoaded(recipeData: $recipeData)';
}
```

**Error in Console**
[image]
[image]

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following _Exception was thrown building BlocBuilder<RecipeBloc, RecipeState>(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<RecipeBloc?>], state: _BlocBuilderBaseState<RecipeBloc, RecipeState>#d4a99):
Exception: Something went wrong

The relevant error-causing widget was
BlocBuilder<RecipeBloc, RecipeState>
package:footballplayers/homeScreen.dart:45
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      _HomeScreenState.build.<anonymous closure>
package:footballplayers/homeScreen.dart:71
#1      BlocBuilder.build
package:flutter_bloc/src/bloc_builder.dart:90
#2      _BlocBuilderBaseState.build
package:flutter_bloc/src/bloc_builder.dart:166
#3      StatefulElement.build
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4919
#4      ComponentElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4806
#5      StatefulElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4977
#6      Element.rebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4529
#7      ComponentElement._firstBuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4787
#8      StatefulElement._firstBuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4968
#9      ComponentElement.mount
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4781
...     Normal element mounting (19 frames)
#28     Element.inflateWidget
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3817
#29     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:6350
#30     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:6362
...     Normal element mounting (91 frames)
#121    _InheritedProviderScopeElement.mount
package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:411
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#128    SingleChildWidgetElementMixin.mount
package:nested/nested.dart:222
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#135    SingleChildWidgetElementMixin.mount
package:nested/nested.dart:222
...     Normal element mounting (15 frames)
#150    _InheritedProviderScopeElement.mount
package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:411
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#157    SingleChildWidgetElementMixin.mount
package:nested/nested.dart:222
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#164    _NestedHookElement.mount
package:nested/nested.dart:187
...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
#171    SingleChildWidgetElementMixin.mount
package:nested/nested.dart:222
...     Normal element mounting (24 frames)
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 

'[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("name")
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:38:5)
#1      ApiServices.getRecipe
package:footballplayers/services/api_services.dart:24
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      new RecipeBloc.<anonymous closure>
package:footballplayers/bloc/recipe_bloc.dart:15
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      Bloc.on.<anonymous closure>.handleEvent
package:bloc/src/bloc.dart:211
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Thanks in advance for stackoverflow community.